# Multiple rowspans in the same column

Tags: html, html-table

is there a way to have multiple rows with the rowspan="2" attribute in the same column?

E. g.

```
1. column      |      2. column      |      3. column
td rowspan="2"    td (rowspan=1)        td (rowspan=1)
                  td (rowspan=1)        td (rowspan=1)
td rowspan="2"    td (rowspan=1)        td (rowspan=1)
                  td (rowspan=1)        td (rowspan=1)
td rowspan="2"    td (rowspan=1)        td (rowspan=1)
                  td (rowspan=1)        td (rowspan=1)
```

I have tried it, but only the first one is displayed properly, the other ones get a column border like strikethrough line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i tried this and there is no problem:

```
<table border="1">
<tr>    <td rowspan="2">sth</td><td>sth</td><td>sth</td>    </tr>
<tr>    <td>sth</td><td>sth</td>    </tr>
<tr>    <td rowspan="2">sth</td><td>sth</td><td>sth</td>    </tr>
<tr>    <td>sth</td><td>sth</td>    </tr>
<tr>    <td rowspan="2">sth</td><td>sth</td><td>sth</td>    </tr>
<tr>    <td>sth</td><td>sth</td>    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It indeed does, the problem was that I was inserting the code in the table with the css propery border-collapse: collapse. It has to be "separate".